# Angular checkbox and ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.2:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myChkModel" ng-click="vm.myClick(vm.myChkModel)">
```

I don't have the right state in my `myClick` function?

I want the state, after the click.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you let us know what state you expect and then what state you have?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The order of execution of `ng-click` and `ng-model` is ambiguous since they do not define clear priorities. Instead you should use `ng-change` or a `$watch` on the `$scope` to ensure that you obtain the correct values of the *model* variable.

In your case, this should work:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myChkModel" ng-change="vm.myClick(vm.myChkModel)">
```

Comment: @musically_ut Not working for the first time if checkbox is already checked.... Function not getting called. Need help in this

Answer (score 23):

You can use ng-change instead of ng-click:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
        app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
          $scope.vm = {};
          $scope.vm.myClick = function($event) {
                alert($event);
          }
        });     
  </script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myChkModel" ng-change="vm.myClick(vm.myChkModel)">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @cardeol, I would like to ask if I can use modals instead of alert here?

Comment: Assign a modal to $scope. then you can open this modal inside the context.

Answer (score 8):

cardeal's answer was really helpful.  Took it a little further and figured it may help others some where down the line.  Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vtL5x0wh/

And the code:

```
<body ng-app="checkboxExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.value0 = "none";
    $scope.value1 = "none";
    $scope.value2 = "none";
    $scope.value3 = "none";

    $scope.checkboxModel = {
        critical1: {selected: true, id: 'C1', error:'critical' , score:20},
        critical2: {selected: false, id: 'C2', error:'critical' , score:30},
        critical3: {selected: false, id: 'C3', error:'critical' , score:40},

       myClick : function($event) { 
          $scope.value0 = $event.selected;
          $scope.value1 = $event.id;
          $scope.value2 = $event.error;
          $scope.value3 = $event.score;
        }
    };

   }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>


    Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.critical1.selected" ng-change="checkboxModel.myClick(checkboxModel.critical1)">
  </label><br/>
  <label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.critical2.selected" ng-change="checkboxModel.myClick(checkboxModel.critical2)">
   </label><br/>
     <label>Value3:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.critical3.selected" ng-change="checkboxModel.myClick(checkboxModel.critical3)">
   </label><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <tt>selected = {{value0}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>id = {{value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>error = {{value2}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>score = {{value3}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution of ng-click and ng-model is different with angular 1.2 vs 1.6

You must test, with 1.2 and 1.6,

for example, with angular 1.2, ng-click get execute before ng-model, 
with angular 1.6, ng-model maybe get excute before ng-click.

so you get 'true checked' / 'false uncheck' value maybe not you expect