# Pass checkbox value to angular's ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-click

Is there a way to pass to angular directive ng-click the value of the associated input?

In other words, what should replace *`this.value`* in the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" ng-click="checkAll(this.value)" />
```

**PS.** I don't want a workaround to alternate values, I just wonder if is possible to *pass a value of an input as argument to an angular function*.

Comment: Can you please add some more code what in you want in checkAll

Comment: add a model on input and pass it in method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular checkbox and ng-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290738/angular-checkbox-and-ng-click)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do the following things:

- Use [**ng-model**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) if you want to bind a html component to angular scope
- Change `ng-click` to `ng-change`
- If you have to bind some value upon checking and un-checking the checkbox use `ng-true-value="someValue"` and `ng-false-value="someValue"`

> The order of execution of `ng-click` and `ng-model` is ambiguous since
>   they do not define clear priorities. Instead you should use ng-change
>   or a `$watch` on the `$scope` to ensure that you obtain the correct values
>   of the model variable.

Courtesy of [musically_ut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20290803/1575570)

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q3La9teg/)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" ng-model="check" ng-change="checkAll(check)" ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO"/> Citizen
```

Answer (score 12):

Today i wanted to do the same thing and i see nobody answered the actual question. This is against the Angular philosophy, but you can replace "this.value" with "$event.target.checked" :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" ng-click="checkAll($event.target.checked)" />
```

Comment: $event is undefined in a checkbox on ng-change unfortunately

Comment: Pass $event and then in function var checkbox = $event.target.checked works.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning an ng-model to it will return boolean value depending upon the change to it:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" ng-model="checkValue" ng-change="checkAll(checkValue)" />
```

Better to use ng-change rather than ng-click

Comment: There is no much sense to pass the checkValue as argument, cause it anyway available in the model...

Comment: @Serge Yes there is, it allows you to control the flow of data, and if someone else has to read the code it will be much easier to understand where does that data came from.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the checkbox to a value and pass it to `ng-click`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" id="cb1" ng-click="checkAll(value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things. Worked for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" ng-click="onChecked($event.target.checked)" />
```

Comment: event will be undefined here